# Wordpress php mysql LIKE query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$db_item =  $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_wowhead_items WHERE name LIKE %s", "%". "Hello" . "%") );
```

This above one works... But the below one doesn't work!

```
$text = "Hello";
$db_item =  $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM wp_wowhead_items WHERE name LIKE %s", "%". $text . "%") );
```

Where am I missing the syntax? I tried almost every combination with quotes, slashes, escapes...

Comment: out of curiosity could you try `"%$text%"`

Comment: this worked... Thanks. The problem is I tried it before, but it was freezing so I thought it wasn't working. Appereantly somewhere else it was giving "%%" and this was freezing the screen and I wasn't able to actually see it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$db_item =  $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM wp_wowhead_items WHERE name LIKE %s", '%$text%'"
));
```

Comment: thank u, the "'%$text%'" dosen't need " ". just '%$text%'

Comment: @Emmanuel, How to use to get categories using LIKE?

Comment: it doesn't work on wordpress version 5.7, it always generates random guid like this `{d258ecae8e3704c8ad532e3b46f99bdc69c2c746b3fe2b2757f5be7b108912ed}my_keyword{d258ecae8e3704c8ad532e3b46f99bdc69c2c746b3fe2b2757f5be7b108912ed}`

Comment: @JSN I thought I was alone in this been trying to find out whats happening with the crazy output using % seems its 5.7? this isn't cool.

Comment: @Sam, I ended up using remove_placeholder_escape, like this `$db_item = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->remove_placeholder_escape($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_wowhead_items WHERE name LIKE %s", '%$text%'")))`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply, I will give that a go @JSN

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in quotes:

```
$db_item =  $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM wp_wowhead_items WHERE name LIKE %s", "'%". $text . "%'"));
```

Comment: @Weptile: Try running your query in mysql client first to make sure it returns any rows or not.