# Why this SQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i have a bits code to get all postmeta (WordPress) with $wpdb method, but i don't know why the code not working.

```
global $wpdb;

$meta_key   = "'_bbp_vs_name_1', '_bbp_vs_name_2'";
$tags_query = "Po";
$query      = $wpdb->esc_like( $tags_query );
$value      = '%' . $query . '%';

$ajax_teams = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key IN ( $meta_key )
    AND meta_value LIKE %s
    ",
    $meta_key,
    $value
) );

print_r( $ajax_teams );
```

Please help.

Working solutions:

```
$ajax_teams = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key IN ( $meta_key ) 
    AND meta_value LIKE %s
    ",
    $value
) );
```

Comment: You seem to forgot a binding: `WHERE meta_key IN ( %s )`

Comment: @ka_lin tested and not working to

Comment: Can you please explain what are you actually trying to achieve? There might be an alternative. In postmeta, the main columns are key and value. You are trying to grab * using keys and values.

Comment: Also I assume the LIKE statement is ignored, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132250/wordpress-php-mysql-like-query-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind %s in query. But you have given varible direction

```
$ajax_teams = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE meta_key IN ( %s ) 
    AND meta_value LIKE %s
    ",
    $meta_key,
    $value
) );
```

Also change value to :

```
$value      = "'%".$query."%'";
```

Comment: Not working tooo, i update question to fix this :) thanks for inspiration